# How to use Custom Transition in GetPage flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have `CustomPageRoute` that I use for navigating to new page with custom transition.

for navigating I use code below:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    CustomPageRoute(
        NewScreen(),
    ),
),
```

This is works fine, but now I want to use `GetPage` in getx library to add dependencies.

```
GetPage(
    name: Routes.NEW_SCREEN,
    page: () => NewScreen(),
    binding: NewScreenBinding(),
),
```

So I have to navigate with `Get.toNamed(Routes.NEW_SCREEN)` and my custom transition not work.

How can I integrate my custom transition with `GetPage`

This is my custom transition:

```
class CustomPageRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  final Widget child;

  CustomPageRoute(this.child);

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => '';

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 600);

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this can a bit easier approach. Create a class like this...

```
class Go {
  static Future<dynamic> to(dynamic page, {dynamic arguments}) async {
    Get.to(
      page,
      arguments: arguments,
      transition: Transition.fadeIn, // choose your page transition accordingly
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  }
}
```

then inside your view or controller

```
Go.to(
  () => OtpView(),
  arguments: 'your dynamic argument' 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your default transition from main.dart inside the GetMaterialApp widget

```html
GetMaterialApp(
     defaultTransition: Transition.fadeIn,
      //or customTransition
      initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      getPages: [
       ...
      ],
      ...
    );
```

or you can add the transition inside the GetPage object like this:

```html
GetPage(
    name: Routes.NEW_SCREEN,
    page: () => NewScreen(),
    binding: NewScreenBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    //or customTransition
),
```

you can also edit this transition's duration
by editing the default value of

```html
transitionDuration
```

or you can use a CustomTransition object by editing the value of

```html
customTransition
```